# How to make a constant object in c#?

Tags: c#, constants

For example

```
class A
{
    public const B b = new B(); // ??? error, expression being assigned must be constant
}

class B
{
    public int i {get; set;}
}
```

How to make a constant object in c#?

Comment: The referenced duplicate question has a really poor accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` means a compile time constant value therefore it is not possible AFAIK.

If it suits your need you can use `readonly` (in combination with `static`) keyword instead of `const`. However in this case you will not be able to specify this field as a default value for an optional parameter in a method.